# How do I prevent the action center from appearing whenever I left click on my touchpad?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I just installed Windows 10 on my dell xps 13 a few weeks ago, and now whenever I left-click the Windows 10 Action Center will pop up whenever I left-click on my touchpad. I always need to left-click again to make it go away.

Is there a way to disable this from happening?

Comment: I just had this problem. These things did not work for me: I disabled and enabled the touchpad, restarted my laptop, and disabled and enabled the "Four-Finger Tap". However, this other thing seemed to have fixed it: I disabled the touchpad and restarted my laptop with the touchpad being disabled. When the laptop turned back on, the touchpad was enabled and everything was working as normal. I have not tried this in other laptops and I am not sure what made it work again. That is why I post this as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Dell xps12. updating the touchpad driver did not help. but found that simply by disabling then enabling the touchpad cleared the problem for me.

I used the following steps:

1. Right click in the start button.
2. Select Device Manager.
3. Select the touchpad and right click (I used an external mouse to do this)
4. Select Disable.
5. Confirm selection - touchpad is disabled
6. repeat above this time select enable touchpad

Comment: This could have been because the hardware was still using the older driver. Re-enabling the device would have forced it use the newer driver. A reboot would have had a similar effect

Answer (score 1):

Just to share the solution I found - just disable the 4 finger gesture on the Touchpad settings (control panel > hardware > touchpad > tapping).

Comment: I already have multi-finger tap gestures disabled in the control panel (presumably from the last time this happened to me) but it randomly started happening again when I switched on my laptop just now.  Your post prompted me to try a 4-finger tap, which cured it (despite 4-finger tapping being disabled - go figure!)

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution, however this solution disables my right-click:

Turn off the notification by going to Settings > System > Notifications and Actions > Turn System Icons On or Off > Toggle 'Action Center' at the bottom

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/disable-windows-10-side-baraction-center-popping/1a6fe46f-29d7-449f-aabb-b3e758041a80

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, changing the Mouse settings eg 4 Finger Gesture etc. did not help.

The method which fixed it was a variation on that shown above by SteveB, but without a USB External Mouse. I did not have an external mouse so could not Right Click anything.

However, going through SteveB's method above through Device Manager/Touchpad, I was able to revert to an earlier version of the driver. Once restarted, the problem with Action Center had gone. I then updated the driver to the newest driver without the Action Center Toggling problem recurring.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution...

1. Search for "Mouse & Touchpad Settings" from the search function
2. Scroll to "Related Settings" and click "Additional Mouse Options".
3. Click Touchpad tab and click on "Click to change the touch Pad settings" link
4. Touch Pad settings window pops up... Click the "Tapping" tab and in the Touch pad section, Select the option "SWITCH TOUCH PAD OFF"
5. Select ONLY "single finger" and Deselect every other finger tapping
6. Click SAVE and close the window.
7. Problem solved (Restart may not be necessary).

Enjoy.